# D3.js scatterplot not align correctly on line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently I am learning D3.js and facing with an issue. My problem is that when I try to add scatterplots to my line graph, the plots are rendering on the wrong place. I do not really know what I am missing.

The function which is responsible for drawing the scatterplot on mousemove event:

```
 ´var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "zoom")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom)
        .on('mousemove', function() {
            var coords = d3.mouse(container.node());
            // Value on the x scale corresponding to this location
            var xVal = x.invert(coords[0]);
            var d = new Date(xVal.getTime());

            //show the closest point on the left
            var i = 0;
            while (i < JSONdata.measurementPoints.length - 1 && new Date(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime) <= d) {
                i++;
            }

            var _date = new Date(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime),
                _temp = JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementValue;
            d3.select("#actPoint").remove();
            // Update the position of the activePoint element
            d3.select('svg').append('circle')
                .attr("cx", x(_date))
                .attr("cy", y(_temp))
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("id", "actPoint")
                .style({
                    'stroke': 'none',
                    'fill': 'red',
                    'fill-opacity': 0
                });

            console.log(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementDateTime);
            console.log(JSONdata.measurementPoints[i].measurementValue);
        });´
```

I think somewhere in this function I make something wrong, hope you can help me figure out what's the problem:)

Codepen: http://codepen.io/laczko090/pen/jrRPBZ

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution which seems working, I added the margin values to the point position and seems align correctly now.

```
´d3.select('svg').append('circle')
                .attr("cx", x(_date)+40)
                .attr("cy", y(_temp)+20)
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("id", "actPoint")
                .style({
                    'stroke': 'none',
                    'fill': 'red',
                    'fill-opacity': 0
                });´
```